# Is there anyway to add items to an existing list in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

My goal is to take user input from a text field and add it directly to a list in the html when the user clicks the "add" button. When I preview the code in my workspace it allows me to enter text in the text field but it will not display in the section I have designated for my list on the web page. The variables at the beginning of the code are for additional processes that I will add later.

My code is:

```
var buttonone=document.getElementById('add-item-1');
var buttontwo=document.getElementById('add-item-2');
var compareB=document.getElementById('compare');
var resetB=document.getElementById('reset');

//function to add items to first list
function addListOne(addOne,listItem,listOne,list){
    addOne = document.getElementById('item-field-1').value;
    document.getElementById('list-one-item').innerHTML = addOne;
    listOne= document.createElement('li');
    listOne.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addOne));
    list.appendChild(listOne);
}

buttonone.addEventListener( 'click', addListOne, false);
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Your question is too broad. You haven't shown any attempt to solve your own problem and what's written comes off as a "give me teh codes" request.

Comment: They did kind of show their attempted code but its an image they didn't display properly. I fixed that but @Akeem you should really add the code as text. Not an image.

Comment: Ok let me revise my question.

Comment: How is it not working? Is the code running? If it is running is it throwing an exception (look under developer tools-> console)? If so what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using Cloud9 as my workspace and I am trying to locate the debugger to see what the problem may be. So far the code will run without any problems but when I click the add button to submit my test entry the entry will not display in the section I provided for my list to appear.

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one element on the page with `id="list-one-item"`? IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Hmm I have two separate lists. So for my first list the id is   id="list-one-item"  Then for my second list I have id="list-two-item".

Answer (score 0):

I have put your code into a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/s5xzazL1/1/ . Note only the first list and input has the event wired to it.

You can use your browsers developer tools to see the exceptions, e.g. in chrome Menu => More Tools => Developer Tools. If you then see the console you will see the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

When you enter valuer and click the add button, the list is replace by the text you've added, this is due to your code line

```
document.getElementById('list-one-item').innerHTML = addOne;
```

Which is incorrect and should be removed.

The exception how ever is due to the fact that the variable `list` is null. Yet it is being used as an object in the line

```
list.appendChild(listOne);
```

List is null, due to some misunderstanding about the parameters of the click event.

Your code:

```
function addListOne(addOne,listItem,listOne,list){
    ...
}

buttonone.addEventListener( 'click', addListOne, false);
```

Your code is expecting addListOne to be called with 4 parameters, when addListOne is called by the click event only 1 parameter is passed and it is the event.

Therefor you need to find the list yourself with a `document.getElementById`.

Giving the code

```
var buttonone=document.getElementById('add-item-1');
var buttontwo=document.getElementById('add-item-2');
var compareB=document.getElementById('compare');
var resetB=document.getElementById('reset');

//function to add items to first list
function addListOne(event){
    var newText = document.getElementById('item-field-1').value;
    var newListItem= document.createElement('li');
    newListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText));
    var listOne = document.getElementById('list-one-item');
    listOne.appendChild(newListItem);
}

buttonone.addEventListener( 'click', addListOne, false);
```

Seen running at https://jsfiddle.net/s5xzazL1/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I apologize for my response being this late. Let me try the code and see if I can get it to work. Ive been attempting some different methods and almost decided on on using an array. But I would prefer using a much simpler option.